# Restore Image File from an Embedded Linux

Tags: embedded, python, debian

I am working a project and I am running python on my SOM module( Variscite DART-6UL ). The libraries installation take too much time that I need. Because of that I want to take an image file after libraries installation. Is this possible? ( Note : I am using Debian )

Answer (score 2):

For an embedded system, building the system image on a PC is the *normal* case. You *never* develop on the embedded target.

Use the buildroot/openembedded/… framework that's used to generate the system image and integrate the software you need!

Again, this is the normal way to develop embedded systems; you usually do not do the installations on the device, you make sure you have a reliable, reproducible, way of generating a system image, so I'm pretty certain that such a way does exist for your SOM (never heard of "Variscite DART-6UL"), too.

I don't even know how you've ended up in this situation – the [product wiki](https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=DART-6UL) tells us you could either be using Yocto (an openembedded-based system), or debian. In both cases, you'd develop the image (yocto: bitbake image) with its packages on your PC and transfer the final image after building it. For both approaches, the wiki's "Complete Developer Guide" seems to contain detailed instructions on how to build these images (/ rootfs in the case of debian); the `make_var_mx6ul_dart_debian` script contains the list of packages that end up in the image, and for Yocto, it's the usual openembedded way of having layers/recipes that contain what you want.

Comment: Personally I've found Buildroot to be a lot more "new user friendly" than Yocto/OE, there is a *big* learning curve with Yocto, but I can see the advantages of Yocto/OE.

Comment: in this case, the main advantage is "the vendor has a BSP / skeleton for OE" :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will research this.

Comment: How can I add my libraries inside these OS files? Do you have a suggestion about it? Or do you have a suggestion for me to start from the basics?

Comment: @Muhammed_Shn - Hi, You keep writing things in the "Your Answer" box below, which are not answers to your question. Please immediately *stop* doing that. I think you are trying to reply to this answer, so I moved your non-answers to be comments here. Overall: If you need to clarify someone's answer, then write a *comment* on that answer. To add new info, please *edit the question* and add it there. Don't use the "Your Answer" box below, unless you are writing a different, new & *full* solution of your problem, and you want to close the question. See the [tour] & [help] for more info. Thanks.